# genuine Jquery / javascript jpg image resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, resize

This is a resize without using the css width / height, or attr width / height. I am posting a jpg image back to a server that has to be 1024x768, but, the image being posted may be other dimensions based on user interaction (loaded externally).

How do I resize, say for example, a 1124x800 jpg image tp 1024x768 so that it is actually resized, not just tagged up for display by its attr or css values??????

Can this be done with a canvas, or do I need a special jquery plugin?????? Any help gratefully recieved. This is an open source project, so I am not looking for a comercial plugin, if thats whats needed.

Comment: A JPEG resampler implemented in Javascript? Hmm. It'd be slow, I bet. Usually you'd farm off such a job to some server.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this can be done with `<canvas>`.

```
function resize(img, width, height) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

    img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```

I would post the JSFiddle, but it seems as though their servers are down. Here's the usage.

```
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

resize(image, image.width * 0.75, image.height * 0.75);
```

As said in the comments this is however intensive on the browser for larger images.

**Note:** you can only do this with locally hosted images. If you try to pass in an image who's `src` is from a different domain, you will receive `SECURITY_ERR: DOM`.